# How to remove duplicate row ids in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jqgrid

Hi i need some help with an array, when i add an item to an array i need to remove it first otherwise it becomes a duplicate, i have looked over the site at similar questions but i cant find the right approach, i have a function that adds an item to an array if the item is selected in a list as seen below.

```
var updateIdsOfSelectedRows = function (id) {
        var index = $.inArray(id, idsOfSelectedRows);
        var rowData = $("#UnlinkedSamplesTable").getRowData(id);
        var selRowIds = $("#UnlinkedSamplesTable").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow");

        if ($.inArray(id, selRowIds) >= 0)
        {


            idsOfSelectedRows.push(id); // add the id 
            statusesOfSelectedRows.push(rowData.StatusEnum); // add the status
            sampleIdsOfSelectedRows.push(rowData.SampleId); // ad the sample id
        }
        else
        {
            //else remove
            idsOfSelectedRows.splice(index, 1); // remove id from the list
            statusesOfSelectedRows.splice(index, 1); // remove status from the list
            sampleIdsOfSelectedRows.splice(index, 1); // remove sampleid from the list
        }

    };
```

The array is built using selected rows in a jQgrid, i call the update function when a user selects a row with onSelectRow and when a user edits a cell on afterSaveCell as shown below.

```
onSelectRow: function(rowid){
                updateIdsOfSelectedRows(rowid);
            }

afterSaveCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
                Highlight(rowid, 'SampleId');

                if($.inArray(rowid, idsOfSelectedRows) == 0)
                updateIdsOfSelectedRows(rowid);
            }
```

So my question is how can remove the current item from the array before i add the new item to stop duplicates. Thank you for any help with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, i use `inArray(id, idsOfSelectedRows)` to check if the item already exists in the list as shown below.

```
var updateIdsOfSelectedRows = function (id) {
        var index = $.inArray(id, idsOfSelectedRows);
        var rowData = $("#UnlinkedSamplesTable").getRowData(id);
        var selRowIds = $("#UnlinkedSamplesTable").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow");
        // Check the row is selected
        if ($.inArray(id, selRowIds) >= 0)
        {
            //Check the row does not already exist in the array and if so remove it - this is necessery to avoid duplicates
            if($.inArray(id, idsOfSelectedRows) > -1)
            {
                idsOfSelectedRows.splice(index, 1); // remove id from the list
                statusesOfSelectedRows.splice(index, 1); // remove status from the list
                sampleIdsOfSelectedRows.splice(index, 1); // remove sampleid from the list
            }
            idsOfSelectedRows.push(id); // add the id 
            statusesOfSelectedRows.push(rowData.StatusEnum);
            sampleIdsOfSelectedRows.push(rowData.SampleId);
        }
        else
        {
            //else remove
            idsOfSelectedRows.splice(index, 1); // remove id from the list
            statusesOfSelectedRows.splice(index, 1); // remove status from the list
            sampleIdsOfSelectedRows.splice(index, 1); // remove sampleid from the list
        }
```

inArray returns the index of the element found so if the index is more than -1 then the element exists and can be removed, -1 indicates the element was not found.